# Swift iOS convert ArraySlice to CGFloat

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift2

I have an array with Int values. In this array I need to get the highest value. Until here I have no problem. But now I need to convert this value to a CGFloat.

```
let ordersPerHour = [hour0All, hour1All, hour2All, hour3All, hour4All, hour5All, hour6All, hour7All, hour8All, hour9All, hour10All, hour11All, hour12All, hour13All, hour14All, hour15All, hour16All, hour17All, hour18All, hour19All, hour20All, hour21All, hour22All, hour23All]
let maxOrdersPerHourVal = ordersPerHour.sort().suffix(1)
```

How can I convert `ArraySlice` to `CGFloat`? All I have tried failed :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let maxOrdersPerHourVal = ordersPerHour.sort.last!`

or

`let maxOrdersPerHourVal = ordersPerHour.max()`

will get the max value in an array.

Then you can cast as normal `var floatVal = CGFloat(maxOrdersPerHourVal)` if you need to cast the value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `sort` here. Just use `max()` (or `maxElement()` in older versions of Swift). That will return an Int rather than a slice.